# How to share Ubuntu's XAMPP installation with Windows 7 running on vmWare Workstation within Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, xampp, vmware, sharing

I am running **Ubuntu 10.10** and also **Windows 7** under **vmWare Workstation** within Ubuntu.

My internet connection in vmWare is shared from the host as 'NAT'

I am using XAMPP on Ubuntu for developing sites. I use `http://localhost/mysite` to open the site under development in Ubuntu.

I wanted to use a similar command to open these sites in the Windows 7 installation under vmWare.

While browsing some of the topics I came to know that it is possible by using some IP of 'NAT'.

I am totally new to Linux and vmWare both. Just migrated to Linux from Windows and need help understanding it in detail.

Kindly help me with the process of How to access these sites in vmWare.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMWare's installer should set up a new network interface on your Ubuntu system, check `ifconfig -a` to find its IP address.

Make sure your webserver is listening on either `0.0.0.0` OR (`127.0.0.1` AND the vmware-interface IP address).

From the Windows system, try typing in `http://<vmware-interface-ip>/mysite`. Hopefully it'll go. You can check the windows networking control panels to see what the gateway address is, it'll probably match.

I hope this gets it going for you.